# How do i make this select on a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to SQL Server and I am having problems figuring out how to make functions.

I'm trying to make this select based on a user int input. This input would take place of the number 8 on a.ID_Aluno=8

```
SELECT 
    a.ID_ALUNO, b.ID_ALUNO, b.ID_Registo, c.ID_Registo, c.Classificacao
FROM 
    Aluno a, Registo b, Avaliação c 
WHERE 
    a.ID_Aluno = 8 
    AND b.ID_Aluno = a.ID_Aluno 
    AND b.ID_Registo = c.ID_Registo
```

I need this number (in this case its 8) to be provided by the user

This was my bad attempt:

```
ALTER FUNCTION CalculaMedia
    (@input INT)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ALUNO INT
    DECLARE @MEDIA FLOAT

    SET @ALUNO = @input

    SET @MEDIA = (SELECT SUM(c.Classificacao * d.Valor_Componente) / COUNT(c.Classificacao)
                  FROM Aluno a, Registo b, Avaliação c, Componente d
                  WHERE a.ID_Aluno = @ALUNO 
                    AND b.ID_Aluno = a.ID_Aluno 
                    AND b.ID_Registo = c.ID_Registo 
                    AND c.ID_Componente = d.ID_Componente)

    RETURN @MEDIA 
END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](http://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also, your aliases should be relevant to the tables. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: So what was wrong with your attempt? Bad result? and error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with integer you probably should make conversion to float so the division give you more accurate result.

```
SELECT 1.0 * SUM(c.Classificacao * d.Valor_Componente) / COUNT(c.Classificacao)
```